# Error in summary.connection(connection): invalid connection

Tags: foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I am using the foreach %dopar% and I get that error. I read that I should register a backend before. I am not sure how to do this in Windows. Can you help me, please?

A chunk of the code below:

```
`library(doParallel)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
# [...]
if (parallelize && ncores > 1) 
{
  # Initialize parallel processing
  cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  # This works, it prints the correct number of cores
  cat("Running in parallel using ", getDoParWorkers(), " cores.\n")
}
bw.values <- seq(lower, upper, length.out = 100)
bw <- numeric(neq)
for (j in 1:neq)
{
  # The error happens here
  result <- foreach::foreach(bw = bw.values, .combine = 'c') %dopar% 
  {
    mse <- .tvOLS.cv(bw = bw, x = x, y = y[, j], z = z, cv.block = cv.block, 
                      est = est, tkernel = tkernel, singular.ok = singular.ok, 
                      parallelize = parallelize, ncores = ncores)
    return(mse)
  }
  bw[j] <- bw.values[which.min(result)]
}
if (parallelize && ncores > 1)
  stopCluster(cl)`
```

I am trying to parallelise a cross-validation process.